# PyFlink "pipeline.classpaths" vs $FLINK_HOME/lib

Tags: java, apache-flink, classloader, flink-sql, pyflink

What is the difference between class loading classes passed as part of PyFlink `pipeline.classpath` config and putting them into a `$FLINK_HOME\lib` directory?

When I want to use `flink-sql-connector-kafka-*.jar` it works fine just passing it using `pipeline.classpath` but when I want to use something that has some external dependencies like `flink-avro-*.jar` that needs `avro-*.jar` jars. It seems to load `flink-avro-*.jar`  but it looks like it fails to load `avro-*.jar` and throws:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder
```

When I am dding `avro-*.jar` to `$FLINK_HOME\lib` it works just fine.

Comment: Seems that if I use `flink-sql-avro-*.jar` that do have org.apache.avro inside shaded directory it works fine. What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException are different

1. **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** This exception indicates that the
   class was not found on the classpath. This indicates that we were
   trying to load the class definition, and the class did not exist on
   the classpath.
2. **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** This exception indicates that the JVM
   looked in its internal class definition data structure for the
   definition of a class and did not find it. This is different than
   saying that it could not be loaded from the classpath. The point is,
   a NoClassDefFoundError is not necessarily a classpath problem.

flink-sql-avro-*.jar is a shaded jar which will relocate the path of org.apache.flink:flink-avro org.apache.avro:avro

Judging from the NoClassDefFoundError, there may be a conflict between the avro version dependencies

Comment: Using flink-sql-avro-*.jar instead of flink-avro-*.jar worked.